# How to pass a .pem key in GitHub actions via environment variable without characters causing YAML parsing issues

Tags: python, yaml, cryptography, github-actions, ssh-keys

I have a GitHub environment secret `{{ secrets.GITHUBAPP_KEY }` that holds a .pem key, in a workflow step, I'm trying to pass the secret to an env variable `GITHUBAPP_KEY`

```
  - name: Do Certain Step
    run:  Insert fancy command here
    env:
      GITHUBAPP_KEY: "${{ secrets.GITHUBAPP_KEY }}"
```

Here is the error the GitHub actio workflow gets when I run it:

error: error parsing STDIN: invalid Yaml document separator: --END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"

The key is the correct format, I have also wrapped double quotes around the secrets context, yet, the file still does not get parsed correctly.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Did you try single quotes?

Comment: If single quotes don't work, you can try passing it as multine string using `|` like [this](https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/#eJxVjUsKgDAMRPc9xSBu6wF6Gy0Bf7RiEkHUu9sqimYxMPMeJAaHSbk1fWzYGcB3OYFZA9uYqDYaRO1YC7FciIUmvi3AgsLylHwDrQ77ZwDKbQOTn0m4ShjH8eL05m+TbyOKMmnFCRT+KIA=).

Comment: @Azeem, your second suggestion solved the issue for me. If you reply to this question with an answer, I can provide you credit for helping me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the SSH private key is spanned over multiple lines, you can assign it to an env var as a multiline string by using pipe `|` like this:

```yaml
env:
  GITHUBAPP_KEY: |
    ${{ secrets.GITHUBAPP_KEY }}
```

See https://yaml-multiline.info/ for interactive examples.

Comment: Will that indent the second and following lines of the key when expanding the template appropriately? THe template exmpander doesn't necessarily need to interpret the YAML before expanding (most don't), but I have seen several that hapily start the character after the first newline in the leftmost column.

Comment: @Anthon: Yes, apparently, the expansion seems to be working fine with proper indentation of all the lines in this context.